# Import Error: /lib/libgdal.so.26: undefined symbol: TIFFReadRGBATileExt, version LIBTIFF_4.0

Tags: linux, c++, gdal, libtiff

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal-Fossa)

I get this error while running running opensfm binaries. This is not related to opensfm as it has run correctly on previous ubuntu20.04 installation.

Error seems to indicate that libgdal is looking for LIBTIFF Version 4.0 but I can't find/install a matching libtiff4 / libtiff4-dev package for ubuntu 20.04

Following results I got while debugging:

**Installed TIFF Packages**

`>> apt list --installed libtiff*`

```
libtiff5-dev/focal-security,focal-updates,now 4.1.0+git191117-2ubuntu0.20.04.8 amd64 [installed]
libtiff5/focal-security,focal-updates,now 4.1.0+git191117-2ubuntu0.20.04.8 amd64 [installed]
libtiffxx5/focal-security,focal-updates,now 4.1.0+git191117-2ubuntu0.20.04.8 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

**Installed LIBGDAL Packages**

`>> apt list --installed libgdal*`

```
libgdal26/focal,now 3.0.4+dfsg-1build3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

**Dependency of libgdal**

`>> ldd /usr/lib/libgdal.so.26.0.4 | grep tif`

```
libgeotiff.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgeotiff.so.5 (0x00007f47d15cb000)
libtiff.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 (0x00007f47d154a000)
```

Please let me know how I can get rid of this error. Thanks.

Comment: Tried removing libtiff from conda environment as suggested for similar issue here(https://github.com/colmap/colmap/issues/188#issuecomment-477341255). This error was gone but that also uninstalled Pillow package(necessary for my work) which depends on libtiff. Installing back Pillow also installed libtiff4.5(pkgs/main/linux-64::libtiff-4.5.0-h6a678d5_2) leading to earlier error.

Comment: *I get this error while running running opensfm binaries. This is not related to opensfm as it has run correctly on previous ubuntu20.04 installation* It 100% **is** related to opensfm. The version of libtiff is not what the opensfm binaries expect. Did you perhaps copy over binaries from your Ubuntu 20.04 installation, instead of building against the libraries you have on your newer system?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I did a fresh build after deleting old build folder. Can you suggest how to change to lower(4.0) libtiff version?

Comment: Your build must have someone have picked up headers of the old version, which is not what your system has as libraries

Answer (score 1):

It seems Conda Environment's libtiff4.5 was the problem. Did the following for resolving:

1. conda uninstall libtiff
2. conda install libtiff=4.0.8
3. pip install Pillow==2.2.2

In step 3, I ended up using pip instead of conda because it was not able to resolve conflicts due to the libtiff=4.0.8 versions compatible with Pillow.

Comment: Doing conda install Pillow in step 3 worked and solved the problem.